# UINavigationController back button half works in iPad landscape orientation

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

In an iPad application with a UINavigationController, everything works in portrait mode but in landscape mode the back button sometimes only goes back half a level.  That is to say, on the first press the title bar animates as if it was popping a controller, and on the second press it animates the content popping.

Has anyone found a solution to this?  The contradictory solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694613/uinavigationcontroller-navigation-stack-problems-in-landscape-mode) did not help.  I have a shouldAutorotate method in the navigation controller but no others.

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)inOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Edit:

actually, the first click pops the content and the second click pops the navigation bar.

Comment: What about in the view controller that is "under" your navigation controller.

Comment: I have an exactly the same problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [David F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694613/uinavigationcontroller-navigation-stack-problems-in-landscape-mode) figured out but I did not grok, every view controller must implement a shouldAutorotate method if the navigation controller does.  Even though it will go ahead and rotate, and you do not need it on the iPhone, somehow the iPad thinks a view controller needs a double pop if it does not respond to that method with the same result as the navigation controller.